# Sending unaccompanied baggage from Japan to USA

Tags: usa, japan, shipping

After spending a good amount of time in Japan, I realize that I have accumulated more stuff than I could carry in my flight (which allows me 2 check-in pieces free of cost, but this is a third piece).

Thus, I would like to send a full size suitcase, which would be about 20kg from Japan to Atlanta,GA. Now the catch is that I don't care how long it takes as long as it arrives safe and sound.

The catch is I myself am not directly going to the US, rather I am first taking a flight to India (NRT - DEL w/ Air India) and then after a short trip of about 10 days, a flight with Lufthansa from DEL - FRA - ATL. After carefully considering, taking a 3rd piece with me is not an option I believe.

My current best bet is to use [Japan Post](http://www.post.japanpost.jp/int/charge/list/parcel3_en.html#)'s Surface Mail service which would cost me about 10,000 JPY but will take about 2 months. Are there,

- Any cheaper options with a similar time frame
- Option with similar cost but with a shorter time frame

If the options involve lugging the 3rd piece with me on the flights, I will be happy to do that as well, but my research has told me that this is quite unlikely.

Comment: @pnuts Mostly worn clothing and some memorabilia.

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for the tip! I'll make sure to put a disinfectant inside the suitcase when I ship them.

Comment: @pnuts That is very odd indeed, do you have any sources on that which I could read probably?

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for that link! Fortunately *Japan* is not there in that list either, so it might be that I might not have any issues, do let me know if you find something specific to this though, although I will not be carrying any commercial goods, only personal artifacts.

Comment: You can also try with [sflworldwide](https://www.sflworldwide.com/)

Answer (score 1):

One of the best long distance courier to US option is [Bombino Express](http://www.bombinoexp.com/). Their prices are reasonable, quick delivery and trackable. I have used them in the past and loved their service. I have used it from India so do not know how their service is from Japan. Play with their rates sites [here](http://www.bombinoexp.com/Rates.aspx) and you can check what is the better option for you

- Ship it directly from Japan to US
- Take it with you to India, then ship it from there

Additionally also compare it with [FedEx Ground](http://www.fedex.com/us/fedex/shippingservices/package/ground.html) incase they ship from where you would like to. Both these options would be certainly quicker than 2 months.

Comment: I tried filling in the rates using 45 lbs. and 20 inch by 20 inch by 20 inch and the answer I get from India to USA is $476! whereas Japan to USA is no better with $443. :( Any other ideas?

Comment: I would suggest call them, I have been able to send stuff with pretty low cost, much lesser than 476